# openID extracting info other than email

Tags: facebook, email, openid, gmail

I was considering using openID for a site I am thinking of building but it does not look like I can get any information extracted out other than the email. I would like to extract other information such as first, last name, address, etc when available. Are they other alternatives that would allow me to get this type of info from accounts such as gmail and facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the end-user allows you access to such data, you can absolutely request more data through OpenID. It's called Attribute Exchange: you can see the spec [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html) or search Google for the implementation info you need.

Answer (score 0):

For GMail, look at the [GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/).
For Facebook, look at the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: This is fine an all but I would have to learn 2 different API's. Maybe not worth it for me at this time.